# Undefined property: DOMNodeList::$textContent when to parse web

Tags: php, xpath

In my code1,it can parse the web to get the td content for me.

code1

```
<?php
    $url='http://www.sse.com.cn/marketservices/tradingservice/shhksc/eligible/';
    $html =  file_get_contents($url);
    $dom = new DOMDocument();
    @$dom->loadHTML($html);
    $xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
    $nodes = $xpath->query('//div[@id="hk_view"]//table[@class="tablestyle"]//tr//td[position()<4 and position()>1]');
    foreach($nodes as $node){
        echo $node->textContent.'</br>';}     
?>
```

Now i change other format to parse the web.

code2

```
<?php
    $url='http://www.sse.com.cn/marketservices/tradingservice/shhksc/eligible/';
    $html =  file_get_contents($url);
    $dom = new DOMDocument();
    @$dom->loadHTML($html);
    $xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
    $nodes = $xpath->query('//div[@id="hk_view"]//table[@class="tablestyle"]//tr');
    foreach($nodes as $node){
        $sub =$xpath->query('//td[position()<4 and position()>1]' ,$node);
        echo $sub->textContent.'</br>';}

?>
```

Is the xpath expression wrong ?

```
$sub =$xpath->query('//td[position()<4 and position()>1]' ,$node);
```

It is the result of my code1.

[image]

According to har07's  answer ,code2 was rewrite as code3,there is another problem remain,please test it with my code3 .

code3

```
<?php
$url='http://www.sse.com.cn/marketservices/tradingservice/shhksc/eligible/';
$html =  file_get_contents($url);
$dom = new DOMDocument();
@$dom->loadHTML($html);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$nodes = $xpath->query('//div[@id="hk_view"]//table[@class="tablestyle"]//tr');
foreach($nodes as $node){
    $sub =$xpath->query('//td[position()<4 and position()>1]' ,$node);
    foreach($sub as $s){
    echo $s->textContent.'</br>';
    }
}
?>
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem isn't in the xpath expression you use. As the error message suggests, `query()` returns `DOMNodeList` which doesn't have `textContent` property. It is `DOMNode` that have `textContent`.

You need to iterate through the `DOMNodeList` to access it's individual `DOMNode` member, and access `textContent` property on each `DOMNode` :

```
foreach($nodes as $node){
    $sub = $xpath->query('.//td[position()<4 and position()>1]' ,$node);
    foreach($sub as $s){
        echo $s->textContent;
    }
}
```

Comment: other problem remain ,i have edited post according your answer.

Comment: $sub = $xpath->query('.//td[position()<4 and position()>1]' ,$node); it is the right way.

Comment: $sub = $xpath->query('//td[position()<4 and position()>1]' ,$node); it is the wrong way

Comment: dot in the xpath expression makes the difference.

Comment: @it_is_a_literature nah, you figured it out before I added explanation to my updated code. `.` before `//` makes the xpath relative to current context `$node`, without `.` the xpath starts searching from the beginning of the XML doc.